# Is there a limit of sample rate of accelerometer on android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sample-rate

Is it possible to reading data from accelerometer with very high sample rate? I need about an 1-2 KHZ. My sensor is can read data with sample rate 25 KHZ, but on android it reading data with 200-400 HZ sample rate. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

The sample rate depends in the sensor hardware.

Most Android phones are not equipped with high frequency accelerometers.

You can check what your phone sensor supports using `[getHighestDirectReportRateLevel][1]` method of the sensor object.

You can also use the `Sensor` object you get from `SensorManager` to check the exact model of the accelerometer in your phone and look up its speck sheet.